# What is the grammatical name and function of this part of the sentence?

Tags: terminology, functions

In the sentence

> *Conciously postponing a decision* is not the same as indecision.

what is the grammatical name and function of the part in italics?

Comment: Its a **gerund-participial clause** functioning as **subject**.

Comment: @BillJ So that's a function fusion?